# Adding other page content preview on home page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have added pages on my wordpress.com blog and I want the main page should appear like

[image]

is there any widget or way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's I suggest you do:

1. Create a category. E.G "secondary-pages "
2. Create your secondary pages as posts and assign the  category to all of them.
3. Call the category on the home page as shown below and have them display in grids.

   ```
   $query = new WP_Query('category_name=secondary-pages');

   if($query->have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

     <div id="content">

       <?php the_title('<h2 class="post-title">','</h2>') ?>
       <?php echo excerpt(35); ?>... 

       <span class="link">

       <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>">

       continue Reading &rarr; </a> 

       </span><!-- End link --> 

     </div>
     <!-- End Content --> 


   <?php endwhile; ?>
   <?php endif; ?>
   <?php } ?>
   ```

Note: you can use different  category names for the pages but that will increase your page size because you's have to call em individually.

Comment: so this solution can be applicable on free worpress.com blog too? I have no idea how to edit if it is not wordpress.org or should I transfer my blog from com to org to make this change?